# How to pop 2 screen at once in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have not created any routes to navigate between screens. I use Navigator to navigate:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
```

what I have done is navigate to four screens from homePage to success screen:

HomePage => CreatePostScreen => CreateImagePost => SuccessfulScreen

when I reach to successfulscreen I would like to pop two screens and get back to CreatePostScreen.
I do not want to write Navigator.pop(context) two times.

I tried to use this, but it will come up with a black screen:

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => route is CreatePostScreen);
```

but this is not working. I would like to learn how flutter handles widget navigation not by route names and solution to this.

I know something about how navigator class handles with route name but I would like to know how to solve it if I push widgets and its working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're trying to do :

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => route is CreatePostScreen);
```

Doesn't work because route is of type Route, not a widget. This leads to all the routes being popped since no Route satisfies your predicate.

What you should do is push your route with a setting, e.g. :

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage(), settings: RouteSettings(name: "/home")));
```

And then use that in your predicate. E.g. :

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => route.settings.name == "/home");
```

Comment: so when widget converted to route it will not provide its name? or any thing which we can identify it!

Comment: The route takes a WidgetBuilder, not a Widget. It also doesn't expose the Widget that was created by the builder. I suppose you could also filter by WidgetBuilder if you wished, but the route settings seem like a more appropriate way to do it.

Comment: okay what if i push 2 routes with the same name and now i want to get back to the lowest one in stack by popping how to do this?

Comment: Then I'd suggest you either give them different names, or add some arguments to the route.

Comment: Nice share .. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Hope this will help you. You can use `popUntil` method of Navigation Class.

```
int count = 0;
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((_) => count++ >= 2);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to `pop` two screens you can use [cascade operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation) like this:

`Navigator.of(context)..pop()..pop();`

Answer (score 1):

You would try with the below code:
`onPressed: () async {int count = 0; Navigator.of(context).popUtil((_)=> count++>= 2);}`

The code you would refer from is that, you would implement the logic to let the system indicate whether pop continues if it returns false it will keep popping until it the logic returns true
`void popUntil(bool Function(Route<dynamic>) predicate)`