# Pop a screen in between in Flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation

I pushed three screens: `ScreenOne` > `ScreenTwo(1)` > `ScreenTwo(2)`

I'm at the second instance of `ScreenTwo` now, but I want to remove the first instance of `ScreenTwo` from the stack, so it should be `ScreenOne` > `ScreenTwo(2)`.

When launching `ScreenTwo(2)` I know I shouldn't remove `ScreenTwo(1)` from the stack yet, so I can't just call `Navigator.replace()`. I really need to have `ScreenOne` > `ScreenTwo(1)` > `ScreenTwo(2)` for some time, and then remove the first instance of `ScreenTwo(1)`.

How I can handle it? `Navigator.pop()` and similars only take into account the screen or screens on top of the stack.

If someone needs more context, this is for a phone app. Not an app for phones, but an app that mimics the behavior of a phone. So in reality, we have `HomeScreen` > `CallScreen(Caller1)` > `CallScreen(Caller2)`. As the app can handle different calls at a time the first approach has been to map every call to a `CallScreen` and let every screen handle their own call events, so the first call can finish while the user is talking in the second one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pop 2 screen at once in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69454634/how-to-pop-2-screen-at-once-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in this post:
[How can I pop to specific screen in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59212860/how-can-i-pop-to-specific-screen-in-flutter)

I quote:

If you didn't define any route in the MaterialApp then you need to define at the time of push.

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
      return SecondPage();
    },
      settings: RouteSettings(name: 'SecondPage',),
    ));
```

You need to define the same route name

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route){
  return route.settings.name == 'SecondPage';
})
```

;

Or as an alternative if you did define the routes you can use that:

```
pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            '/BottomNavigation', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

Comment: This can also help with some general knowledge https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But that's not exactly my situation. I'll add a bit more context to the question to better explain the context :·)

Comment: Is that maybe the method you are looking for? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/removeRoute.html

Comment: I was just looking at it. But it means I have to make everything work with named routes which is not the case right now :sweat:

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is most suitable that you go from screen1 > Screen2 > replace previous with Screen3

Use this navigation from screen 2 to screen 3.
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context,"Third Screen");

Comment: Thanks for the idea! But I don't know when Screen2 should disappear. Maybe it should be there when Screen3 is popped or not. I don't know it at Screen3 launch time.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are going to screen 3?